# How to calculate the bandwidth of a synchronous bus with overlap in bus transfer and reading next data?

Tags: computer-architecture, bus, bandwidth, synchronous

I am working through problems in [Saylor Academy's computer architecture course](https://learn.saylor.org/course/view.php?id=71). I can't understand how this kind of problem is solved:

> Consider a 32-bit synchronous bus with f = 125 Mhz, an 8 nsec clock cycle (CK), send address/data takes 1CK each, 2CKs between bus operations, a memory access time of 200 nsec, bus transfer and reading next data overlap, block size 8 words. What is the bandwidth for 256 4-byte words to be transferred across the bus?

The given solution:

> The BW calculation is as follows: 256/8 blocks gives 32 total transactions. Each memory access takes 200/8 = 25 clock cycles. Send data/address + idle time is 8 clock cycles for a total of 34 clock cycles including 1 clock cycle for the initial memory read.....

I could not understand this:

> Send data/address + idle time is 8 clock cycles

I expect that it would be 1 cycle for send data, 1 cycle for send address and 2 cycles idle time, for a total of 4 cycles. Why is one cycle required for the initial memory read?

Comment: Please expand the solution quote to include the first word of the next sentence.

Comment: Does the solution mention explicitly where *bus transfer and reading next data overlap*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A word is assumed to be 1 byte. The bus is 32-bits wide. To transfer 8 words i.e. 64 bits, it needs 2 send data and send address operations.

So it will be
2 x (1 cycle for send data + 1 cycle for send address + 2 cycles idle time) = 2 x 4 = 8 cycles

One additional cycle for the additional memory read is required because during the first cycle, bus transfer can't be overlapped with reading next data.

Comment: `8 words i.e. 64 bits` from the question: `4-byte words`: word size = bus width = 32 for 256 bits/block.